# Intercept console.log but keep stack

Tags: javascript, logging

I know its easy to intercept a function in js, among other ways:

```
console.log = (function () {
var log = console.log;

return function () {
    alert(arguments);
    log.apply(console, arguments);
})();
```

but Is there a way to wrap console.log such that when a user calls

```
console.log("hi")//in random.js
```

in the console it shows the random.js origin, and not the location of the intercept?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `try/catch` rather than returning a function:

```
console.log = Function("a", "try { console.info(a); } catch(e){return e}");
```

Comment: This merely seems to create a vmxxx.js file on the stack in chrome. not saying that it came from x.js