# javascript: console log use parent scope

Tags: javascript, logging

Is it possible using some javascript trickery to tell `console.log` which line number it should output?

Suppose, we the following simple example:

```
function Logger () {
    this.debug = function(msg) {
        // do some stuff with msg
        console.log(msg);
    };
}

var log = new Logger();
log.debug("Hello");
```

If you open the page, Chrome shows up this:

[image]

This indicates that the message was logged at `main.js:4` but what I really want is that it shows `main.js:9`. Because line 9 is where the logger was called.
For this simple case it doesn't make much difference, but when the Logger is in a separate file, it always shows `logger.js` instead of the class which called the logger.

The Logger class should do some additional stuff with the logged message (e.g. sending it to the server), thus I can't just use `this.debug = console.log`.

*EDIT*:

There are already some similar questions, but all of them just add an additional line to the output, which isn't clickable to jump to the corresponding line:

- [Extending console.log without affecting log line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9559725/extending-console-log-without-affecting-log-line)
- [console.log wrapper that keeps line numbers and supports most methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11308239/console-log-wrapper-that-keeps-line-numbers-and-supports-most-methods)
- [Get console wrapper to log message on correct line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27449382/get-console-wrapper-to-log-message-on-correct-line?rq=1)
- [Getting Chrome's console.log to display the line that called a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21030027/getting-chromes-console-log-to-display-the-line-that-called-a-function)
- [Custom console.log that keeps line number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25717947/custom-console-log-that-keeps-line-number?rq=1)
- [Intercept console.log but keep stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25540308/intercept-console-log-but-keep-stack?rq=1)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28457477/javascript-console-log-change-line-number-to-somewhere-higher-in-the-stack?rq=1

Answer (score 4):

The first thing that comes to my mind is creating a new `Error` object to get the stack trace and then find the line that called your method, like this:

```
function Logger () {
    this.debug = function(msg) {
        // do some stuff with msg

        //TODO: document this line
        var callerLine = new Error().stack.split('\n')[2];
        console.log(msg, callerLine);
    };
}

var log = new Logger();
log.debug("Hello");
```

Basically I'm splitting the error's stack in each newline and ignoring the first and second lines (The error message and your own method in the stack, respectively).

Comment: This is a solution which is not yet perfect.
The output is now: `Hello     at http://localhost/main.js:12:5       main.js:7`
It would be nicer to have just the relative path.

Comment: Unforunately the Error.prototype.stack property is non standard conform, so this isn't a valid solution. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/stack

Comment: This code is not even meant to work in production because your JS should be minified, fitting everything in as few lines as possible. This is not meant to be a cross-browser thing, just a way to simplify logging, so I don't see how not being a standard makes this a "invalid solution"

Comment: Well the problem is that I'm using Typescript which complains at this line that `TS2339: Property 'stack' does not exist on type 'Error'.`